# CSS make Image centered on mobile view while keeping height the same?

Tags: html, css

Here's my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/white-pine-8tfws?file=/styles.css

Right now if you shrink the screen, the image just disappears into the right side. I'd like to have the image centered on smaller screen sizes instead of showing just the left side of the image. I tried to just have it span the full width, but when I shrink it the quality becomes terrible and just looks blurry.

This website is an example effect I'm trying to replicate https://www.jamesedition.com/real_estate except maybe keep the height the same ratio

I hard coded the  tags in my HTML, so I don't know how I would position it since I can't use the background: URL() property because it's a slider and I have to map through a data file.

Here's the css

```
           * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .main {
        position: relative;
        max-height: 1100px;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        margin-top: -60px;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      .section {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: -1;
      }

      h1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 10%;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }

      img {
        height: 100vh;
        width: auto;
        min-width: 100vw;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace your img css, hope this is what you are looking for,

```
img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center top;
}
```

Comment: nah cause then it shrinks my images into a square and leaves white space on both sides. I need my images to span the whole vw of the screen

Answer (score 0):

```
      height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100vw;
  background: url('src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564013799919-ab600027ffc6?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work cause I'm mapping through a data file with a bunch of images. Hence I can't use background URL like I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

add this style in your image:

```
  height: auto;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Here add a `min-height` if required.

it'll keep your image full width and keep height auto so that image quality will not be compromised. It's quite hard to keep one image for all devices and don't lose the quality, since viewport changes and aspect ratio also needs to be changed.